# get closest date from a multiple id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement to match the records of idno in @sampleTrans with the nearest date (rodt) from @sampleReceipt. I have the query but it gives me a different result. any help is very much appreciated. see below sample DDL and expected result. Thank you.

```
DEclare @sampleReceipt table
(
csno varchar(50), idno varchar(50), rdt datetime, descript varchar(35))

insert @sampleReceipt values ('ABCDE5B12AG123383814.0611','ABCDE5B12AG12338','2018-04-18 07:34:34.000','receive')
insert @sampleReceipt values ('ABCDE5B12AG123383064.3556','ABCDE5B12AG12338','2018-01-02 10:59:11.000','receive')
insert @sampleReceipt values ('ABCDE5B12AG123383064.3559','ABCDE5B12AG12338','2018-08-14 10:59:11.000','receive')

insert @sampleReceipt values ('ABCDE5B12AG333352814.2771','ABCDE5B12AG33335','2018-06-02 02:56:07.000','receive')
insert @sampleReceipt values ('12345678901234612813.6785','1234567890123461','2018-05-16 18:55:11.000','receive')
insert @sampleReceipt values ('11111118901234612813.6785','1111111890123461','2018-07-16 19:55:11.000','receive')
insert @sampleReceipt values ('22222228901234612813.6785','2222222890123461','2018-07-19 06:59:10.000','receive')

Declare  @sampleTrans table
(id varchar(50), idno nvarchar (50), recover varchar(50),  dt datetime, roid varchar(35), linestatus int, lineid varchar(35), opdesc varchar(35) ,descript varchar(35))

insert @sampleTrans values ('SAL00CABCDE5B12AG12338','ABCDE5B12AG12338','58922','2018-02-15 10:48:03.000','SAL00C',1,'H_LineD','created','created')
insert @sampleTrans values ('SAL00CABCDE5B12AG12338','ABCDE5B12AG12338','58922','2018-03-20 23:20:03.000','SAL00C',1,'H_LineD','complete','good')
insert @sampleTrans values ('SAL00AABCDE5B12AG12338','ABCDE5B12AG12338',''     ,'2018-06-15 23:48:03.000','SAL00A',1,'H_Dis','complete','good')
insert @sampleTrans values ('SAL00AABCDE5B12AG12338','ABCDE5B12AG12338',''     ,'2018-06-13 14:59:24.000','SAL00A',1,'H_Dis','created','created')
insert @sampleTrans values ('SAL00BABCDE5B12AG12338','ABCDE5B12AG12338','58922','2018-06-30 15:02:25.000','SAL00B',1,'H_kt','created','created')
insert @sampleTrans values ('SAL00BABCDE5B12AG12338','ABCDE5B12AG12338','58922','2018-07-05 13:20:41.000','SAL00B',1,'H_kt','complete','good')
insert @sampleTrans values ('BOI002ABCDE5B12AG33335','ABCDE5B12AG33335','80539','2018-07-10 10:33:01.000','BOI002',3,'H_Dis','complete','bad')
insert @sampleTrans values ('BOI002ABCDE5B12AG33335','ABCDE5B12AG33335','80539','2018-06-26 08:42:01.000','BOI002',3,'H_Dis','created','created')
insert @sampleTrans values ('BAL0451234567890123461','1234567890123461','','2018-06-13 21:37:33.000','BAL045',1,'H_Dis','created','created')
insert @sampleTrans values ('BAL0451234567890123461','1234567890123461','','2018-06-15 23:43:01.000','BAL045',1,'H_Dis','complete','good')
insert @sampleTrans values ('BAL0561234567890123461','1234567890123461','70418','2018-07-05 12:25:31.000','BAL056',1,'H_kt','complete','good')
insert @sampleTrans values ('BAL0561234567890123461','1234567890123461','70418','2018-06-30 15:03:28.000','BAL056',1,'H_kt','created','created')
insert @sampleTrans values ('BAL0591111111890123461','1111111890123461','70419','2018-07-25 15:03:28.000','BAL059',1,'H_Line','created','created')



select t1.id, t1.idno, t1.recover, t1.dt, t1.roid, t1.opdesc, t1.lineid , t2.csno, t2.rdt
from @sampleTrans t1
left join @sampleReceipt t2
on t1.idno= t2.idno
and t1.dt >= t2.rdt
order by t1.idno, t1.dt


Expected Result

id----------------------idno--------------recover----dt-----------------------roid----opdesc---lineid----rodt---------------------csno
BAL0591111111890123461--1111111890123461--70419------2018-07-25 15:03:28.000--BAL059--created-- H_Line---2018-07-16 19:55:11.000--BAL0591111111890123461
BAL0451234567890123461--1234567890123461--NULL-------2018-06-13 21:37:33.000--BAL045--created-- H_Dis----2018-05-16 18:55:11.000--BAL0561234567890123461
BAL0451234567890123461--1234567890123461--NULL-------2018-06-15 23:43:01.000--BAL045--complete--H_Dis----2018-05-16 18:55:11.000--BAL0561234567890123461
BAL0561234567890123461--1234567890123461--70418------2018-06-30 15:03:28.000--BAL056--created-- H_kt-----2018-05-16 18:55:11.000--BAL0561234567890123461
BAL0561234567890123461--1234567890123461--70418------2018-07-05 12:25:31.000--BAL056--complete--H_kt-----2018-05-16 18:55:11.000--BAL0561234567890123461
SAL00CABCDE5B12AG12338--ABCDE5B12AG12338--58922------2018-02-15 10:48:03.000--SAL00C--created-- H_LineD--2018-01-02 10:59:11.000--ABCDE5B12AG123383814.0611
SAL00CABCDE5B12AG12338--ABCDE5B12AG12338--58922------2018-03-20 23:20:03.000--SAL00C--complete--H_LineD--2018-01-02 10:59:11.000--ABCDE5B12AG123383814.0611
SAL00AABCDE5B12AG12338--ABCDE5B12AG12338--NULL-------2018-06-13 14:59:24.000--SAL00A--created-- H_Dis----2018-04-18 07:34:34.000--ABCDE5B12AG123383814.0611
SAL00AABCDE5B12AG12338--ABCDE5B12AG12338--NULL-------2018-06-15 23:48:03.000--SAL00A--complete--H_Dis----2018-04-18 07:34:34.000--ABCDE5B12AG123383814.0611
SAL00BABCDE5B12AG12338--ABCDE5B12AG12338--58922------2018-06-30 15:02:25.000--SAL00B--created-- H_kt-----2018-04-18 07:34:34.000--ABCDE5B12AG123383814.0611
SAL00BABCDE5B12AG12338--ABCDE5B12AG12338--58922------2018-07-05 13:20:41.000--SAL00B--complete--H_kt-----2018-04-18 07:34:34.000--ABCDE5B12AG123383814.0611
BOI002ABCDE5B12AG33335--ABCDE5B12AG33335--80539------2018-06-26 08:42:01.000--BOI002--created-- H_Dis----2018-06-02 02:56:07.000--ABCDE5B12AG333352814.2771
BOI002ABCDE5B12AG33335--ABCDE5B12AG33335--80539------2018-07-10 10:33:01.000--BOI002--complete--H_Dis----2018-06-02 02:56:07.000--ABCDE5B12AG333352814.2771
```

Comment: It's very hard to read your data, and you should make an effort to make your question more readable.  That being said, is it allowed for more than one transaction to map to the same receipt or vice-versa?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OUTER APPLY` to get only the closest record - only one record per row, like this:

```
select t1.id, t1.idno, t1.recover, t1.dt, t1.roid, t1.opdesc, t1.lineid , s.csno, s.rdt
from @sampleTrans t1
OUTER APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM @sampleReceipt t2
    WHERE  t1.idno= t2.idno
        and t1.dt >= t2.rdt
    order by t2.rdt

) S
ORDER BY t1.idno, t1.dt
```

Comment: I got incorrect rdt. sample for this idno ABCDE5B12AG12338. it has three different rdt (receive date). This '2018-01-02 10:59:11.000' and '2018-04-18 07:34:34.000' should be match to the closest dt (date) from @sampleTrans. while the thirdt rdt is not exposed yet becuase it has no transaction that match in the date.

Comment: @Jov The above gives you the expected result shown in the question, right?

Comment: i got  wrong result. Here is my new script so far it is working but i dont know if this will work if i have a million of records. 
     [SELECT r.*, p.id, p.idno as idnum, p.recover , p.dt, p.lineid, p.opdesc,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY r.idno,rdt ORDER BY roid DESC) 
     AS Seq
     FROM (SELECT *,LEAD(rdt,1,'20491231') OVER (PARTITION BY idno 
    ORDER BY rdt) AS NxtDate
    FROM @sampleReceipt) r
    JOIN @sampleTrans p
    ON p.idno = r.idno
   AND p.dt BETWEEN r.rdt AND NxtDate]

Comment: Well, it depends on the indexes you have. It will be good if you have PK/index on your id,indo and date columns. Then you can executed your code in advanced and get only the id, indo, column you need to returned - after that, using the columns extracted the rest of the data.

Answer (score 1):

try this one,

```
select t1.id, t1.idno, t1.recover, t1.dt, t1.roid, t1.opdesc, t1.lineid ,
csno=(select top 1 csno from @sampleReceipt t2 order by ABS(DATEDIFF(second,t1.dt,t2.rdt))),
rdt=(select top 1 rdt from @sampleReceipt t2 order by ABS(DATEDIFF(second,t1.dt,t2.rdt)))
from @sampleTrans t1
order by t1.idno, t1.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Have this code so far its working but i'm concerned if this will work if i have million of records or i there any alternative to simplify this code?

```
  SELECT r.*, p.id, p.idno as idnum, p.recover , p.dt, p.lineid, p.opdesc,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY r.idno,rdt ORDER BY roid DESC) 
     AS Seq
     FROM (SELECT *,LEAD(rdt,1,'20491231') OVER (PARTITION BY idno 
    ORDER BY rdt) AS NxtDate
    FROM @sampleReceipt) r
    JOIN @sampleTrans p
    ON p.idno = r.idno
   AND p.dt BETWEEN r.rdt AND NxtDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, it uses `CROSS JOIN` to get all possible combination of rows from both tables, then takes rows, which have smallest difference between dates (using `ROW_NUMBER` function):

```
select * from (
    select st.*,
           sr.csno,
           row_number() over (partition by st.id, st.dt order by abs(datediff(minute, st.dt, sr.rdt)) desc) rn
    from @sampleTrans st
    cross join @sampleReceipt sr
) a where rn = 1
```